# Win Forms Label Updates Super Slow

Tags: c#, winforms, threadpool

I have a Windows Forms application written in C# that does some automated testing. My test runs on the thread pool. The UI has a bunch of labels to display the data read from an external device. During the test, a method writes the new values to a singleton class. The singleton class broadcasts the value change and an event handler in the forms code does the updating after invoking on the UI thread. My problem is that it takes about 1.5 seconds just to update the UI (72 Labels). Why does it take so long? FYI, there is only one event broadcast for all 72 values, not one broadcast for each of the 72 values.

Here is the code (ProgramData.MaximumUnits = 18):

```
this.InvokeIfRequired(() =>
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    var rawData = TestData.Instance.RawDataDisplay;
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < ProgramData.MaximumUnits; i++)
    {
        Frequency1Label[i].Text = rawData[i].F1;
        Frequency2Label[i].Text = rawData[i].F2;
        TempSensorLabel[i].Text = rawData[i].T1;
        UnitInfoLabel[i].Text = rawData[i].ErrorCode;
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
});
```

The elapsed time is usually around 1500ms. I feel like this operation should be performed in less than 100ms.

Why this is a problem: I am displaying externally acquired data that comes in every 1 second. Since it takes 1.5 seconds to update the UI, I am in a serious bind, especially when the data can come in as fast as every half a second.

Comment: @HansPassant The OS tries to do what wrong? Please explain.

Comment: I use Task.Run to run an action on the thread pool. This should be the proper way of running a long process. Our tests can be hours long. They should not run on the UI thread.

Comment: Is it possible WPF would provide better performance?

Comment: Thread pool has limited resources. Maybe you hit the maximum and got into a bottleneck of waiting threads to finish. Just a guess.

Comment: What is `this`? The form? Can you access the labels through the _invoked_ property?

Comment: @Rubens Yes, `this` is the form. I am accessing them by invoking. If I didn't, I would get a cross-thread exception. `InvokeIfRequired` is an extension I use that checks if `InvokeRequired` and then `Invoke`'s if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you're paying the cost of redrawing the form as you change the text of each label. You can try to freeze the form first, by calling `SuspendLayout`, make all of the changes to the different controls, and when you're done call `ResumeLayout` to redraw the whole screen at once.

e.g.

```
SuspendLayout();

try
{
    // Update the labels
}
finally
{
    ResumeLayout(performLayout: true);
}
```

---

Also, check if any of the labels have event handler(s) for the `TextChanged` event, as changing the text of the labels would trigger this event (and it could be doing something that is slowing you down).

Comment: I really thought this would work after reading your answer but unfortunately it didn't reduce the time at all.

Comment: In that case you may want to use a performance profiler such as [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is updating the labels? Will the time changes if you just change the update code to simple loop and assigns simole string there?

Comment: After going back I realized I wanted the parent of the `Label`s, which is a `TableLayoutPanel`. Using `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` worked when I referenced the `TableLayoutPanel` and not the `Form`. Though I did notice it takes a quarter of the time if I comment out `ResumeLayout();` or use `ResumeLayout(false);`. Why is this? Is this because it is not forced to relayout immediately and can do it when it wants? It doesn't make sense that it would take longer to change the labels text property, when using `ResumeLayout()` after doing the actual label property changes.

Comment: `ResumeLayout(true)` calls `PerformLayout`, whilst `ResumeLayout(false)` doesn't. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8aw0sd8.aspx) and [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/windows-forms-layout-managers/184405892) for more details

Answer (score -1):

**Put the code into Form_load**

```
try

{

ResumeLayout(performLayout: true);

}

finally

{

}

This.Refresh();
```

You have to This.Refresh() after the ResumeLayout Method Called

Comment: You have to This.Refresh() after the ResumeLayout Method Called.

Comment: Sorry, but you do not.